# Limit in the integral

Tags: integration, limits

I am working on the following statement:

> Let $y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that  $\lim_{t \to \infty}y(t)=-\infty$ and $g$ is a bounded function. Then
> $$\int_{0}^{t}(y(s)+ g(s)) ds \to -\infty \quad \text{when} \quad t \to \infty.$$

I read this in https://repositorio.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/11449/94213/cardin_pt_me_sjrp.pdf?sequence=1 page 60, equation (3.5). But I am not sure of this statement and of the equation (3.4).

Thank so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the statement but here we assume $y$ is continuous or integrable on any interval with finite length (otherwise, the statement doesn't make much sense).

Let $C$ be a constant such that $|g(s)|<C$ for any $s$. For any $M>C$, there exists $T>0$ such that $t\geq T$ implies $y(t)\leq -M$ since $\lim_{t\to \infty}y(t) = -\infty$. With $T$ fixed, for any $t\geq T$, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_0^t(y(s)+g(s))ds & = \int_0^T(y(s)+g(s))ds + \int_T^t(y(s)+g(s))ds \\
& \leq \int_0^T(y(s)+g(s))ds + \int_T^t(-M+C)\\
& = \int_0^T(y(s)+g(s))ds - (M-C)(t-T) \to -\infty
\end{align*}
as $t \to \infty$ since $M-C>0$.